# Syntax Coloring for a custom list of words in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We are using a custom editor for a specific kind of files. Now the problem here is, i am new to this eclipse related stuff. I have to highlight list of words with a specific colour. I checked online found some rules but i dont have basic idea how to use them. It would be great if someone help me how to add a specific colour for given list of words in custom editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some of your code or more information to be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code put it in your reconciler class : `

```
private final TextAttribute wordAttribute = new TextAttribute(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), new RGB(0, 0, 255));

public static final String[] keywords = { "define your keywords here" };

 ....................................................................

    RuleBasedScanner scanner = new RuleBasedScanner();
    IRule[] rules = new IRule[5]; //set as many rules as you want just change the number in the bracket 

 ....................................................................

    WordRule rule = new WordRule(new IWordDetector() {//the IWordDetector class is an anonymous class so you'll have to define and override this two functions below as you want  

        @Override
        public boolean isWordStart(char c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWordPart(char c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c);
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            rule.addWord(keywords[i], new Token(wordAttribute));
    }
    rules[0] = rule;
    scanner.setRules(rules);
}`
```

I think it should color your words as it does to me.